# SQL Multiplication of multiple rows resulting in one row

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I am doing a query using this syntax:

```
SELECT itemid, description, store, SUM(localcurrencyamount * exchangerate) AS 'US Currency Amount'
FROM item;
```

It is retuning 1 out of 4 rows where it is showing the correct first row itemid, description, and store, but it is adding all of both columns localcurrencyamount and exchangerate multiplication into one field. So my result should be, in row itemid 1, 7156.4047, but I am getting a value of 8426.7303; which is the total value for the new column US Currency Amount of ALL rows (1 through 4).

What is wrong with this syntax that is causing all of that data to be 'lumped' into one field instead over 4? When I ran:

```
SELECT itemid, description, store FROM item;
```

It returned all of the information from 4 rows separately, but when I added SUM(localcurrencyamount * exchangerate) AS 'US Currency Amount' is when the data lumped together into just the first row.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you are missing Group By

Comment: Oh perfect! Thank you. Still learning SQL, so this is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want one row returned, or all 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People in comments seem to think you need GROUP BY, but it sounds like in your case that is not correct. SUM() means just that: it sums up (adds up) rows. You don't want that. You want:

```
SELECT itemid, description, store, (localcurrencyamount * exchangerate) AS 'US Currency Amount'
FROM item;
```

Comment: I actually neglected to add GROUP BY. That sorted it out.

Comment: I also tried your method and that worked too, and is more efficient! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the result for each record separately, don't use `SUM`. `SUM` is an aggregate function that works on a group of records. Use just:

```
SELECT itemid, description, store, (localcurrencyamount * exchangerate) AS 'US Currency Amount'
FROM item;
```